# How can I call Yammer autocomplete api from backend using HttpWebrequest?

Tags: yammer

I need to call Yammer autocomplete GET API (https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked) from backend (aspx.cs) using HttpWebRequest. I am not able to send content body (prefix and models) with GET HttpWebRequest. I tried to replace GET with POST but i am getting error 'Method Not Allowed'.

Appreciate any advice on how to call Yammer autocomplete GET api from backend using HttpWebrequest.

Comment: It's not clear whether this is even a coding question. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: @AdiInbar this is pretty clearly a coding question, but it could indeed be improved. Just because it is outside your realm of expertise or understanding doesn't always mean you can invalidate it.

Comment: You should update your question to include some info such as the HTTP requests being executed in your case. This may provide some pointers as to what is going wrong.

Comment: @BrianLyttle I think you're jumping to conclusions. I didn't "invalidate" it "just because" it's outside my realm of expertise. I was doing a First Posts review, and it definitely needs to either be improved or closed. The reason I said it's not clear if it's even a coding question is that it's so vague that I wasn't 100% sure if he encountered a *coding* issue or whether it's more of a protocol/server issue, so I wasn't sure whether to vote off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem, or more appropriate for serverfault. It's definitely either one or the other.

Comment: Notice, BTW, that the rest of my comment was geared toward providing advice on improving a coding question, which wouldn't make sense if I were assuming that it's not a coding question. Due to the dearth of information, I was accounting for the possibility that the question might not even belong here, but that wasn't the main focus of my feedback.

Answer (score 0):

To use GET you can simply encode the data into the url. Like:

```
"api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?models=user:5&prefix=" + name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to include `Accept: application/json` as header of the request, which is needed to call the autocomplete API from Yammer.

[More information about the Yammer autocomplete API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/autocompleteranked)